# Symlink path always starts from /private/

Tags: java, directory, operating-system, symlink

I wrote a function that creates a symlink to a specific directory inside a given parent directory. It does not create the link directly, but rather create a tmp link, and then move that tmp link to the desired path, as move operation is atomic while overwrite is not.

```
public static void updateMySymlink(final Path parentDir, final String targetDirName) {
    final Path targetPath = parentDir.resolve(targetDirName);
    final Path tempPath = parentDir.resolve("tmp");
    final Path symlinkPath = parentDir.resolve("mySymlink");
    Files.createSymbolicLink(tempPath, targetPath);
    Files.move(tempPath, symlinkPath, ATOMIC_MOVE);
}
```

When I try to unit-test this, I wrote a test like:

```
@Test
public void testSymlinkCreation() {
    final Path targetPath = localRepoPath.resolve("target");
    final Path symlinkPath = localRepoPath.resolve("mySymlink");
    FileUtils.forceMkdir(targetPath.toFile());
    updateMySymlink(localRepoPath, "testCommitId1"); // static method
    assertThat(targetPath).isEqualTo(symlinkPath.toRealPath());
}
```

This test fails with the message:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:</[private/]tmp/testDirToCreate-...> but was:</[]tmp/testDirToCreate-...>
```

No matter how the input paths changes, this `private/` stays the same. I tried asserting for the absolutePaths or for the paths after normalization but it still failed for the same error.

#### My question is, where is this `private/` is coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue was that I'm using `.toRealPath()` only on the `symlinkPath`. Modifying the assertion to:

```
assertThat(targetPath.toRealPath()).isEqualTo(symlinkPath.toRealPath());
```

solved the problem.